# Unable to publish Selfcontained Asp.net 5 core project

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, web-publishing

I have a project that works on my development computer.

I am able to publish it when the deployment mode is set to Framework-dependant and target runtime is set to Portable.
But if I change it to Deployment mode Self Contained and Target Runtime Win-x86 or Win-x64
I get this error:

```
Metadata file 'C:\Sppro\Projects\xxx\Source\xxx ModelCore\bin\Release\net5.0\win-x86\ref\xxx ModelCore.dll' could not be found
```

There is no files in C:\Sppro\Projects\xxx\Source\xxx ModelCore\bin\Release\net5.0\win-x86\ref\

I've tried changing my configuration to X86 or X64 and building, but it does not populate these folders.

Comment: According to your description, I suggest you could try to use this solution:Close Visual Studio
Delete the hidden .vs folder
Reopen Visual Studio and rebuild the solution.

Comment: thanks for your response, but this did not solve the problem